# Symfony2 cache log shows "miss" when it appears to be a hit

Tags: caching, symfony

I am trying to make sure that my application is caching my page correctly. I have the following code in my controller

```
//...in controller
$response = $this->render('FrontBundle:Page:index.html.twig', $data);
$response->setPublic();
$response->setMaxAge(600);
$response->setSharedMaxAge(600);
//this appears only on the first page load
echo 'this was not cached';
return $response;
```

When I load the page for the first time I see **this was not cached**, every subsequent refresh does not show this message so I am pretty sure that my cache is being hit.

However, when I view my log file I see something like the following on every request

```
[11-Apr-2013 UTC] GET /_wdt/462e0da5f0afdfb7ad62760f48e41429e2b86fbd: miss
```

Shouldn't I be seeing a `hit` after the first page load?

Here is the code I am using in app_dev.php as seen [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/http_cache.html#symfony2-reverse-proxy)

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
error_log($kernel->getLog());
```

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't I be seeing a hit after the first page load?

Not for request for `/_wdt` Requests to that URL are requests for *Symfony's* `Web Debug Toolbar` They are never cached. You are only seeing them because you are in the `dev` environment.

Also, requests served from the cache will look like `GET /some_page: fresh`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JamesMohler He's seeing "miss" for /_wdt in his error log. He'll always see "miss" for the Web Debug Toolbar as it's not cached. How is this not an answer? Sure, it's not ten thousand lines long, but every answer doesn't need to be.